# tmap: add rectangular frame around keys in legend of raster map

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, tmap

I need to place a fill-legend for categorical raster data, where white is used to represent ice, on a raster map on white background. I would like to use tmap. Here is a minimum working example that is similar in spirit to my current project.

```
library(tmap)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(stars)
data(land)
land_copy <-
  land %>%
  mutate(cover_simplified =
           fct_other(cover_cls, keep = c("Snow/ice", "Water")))
tm_shape(land_copy) +
  tm_raster(col = "cover_simplified",
            palette = c("white", "lightblue", "brown")) +
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[map produced with tmap, no rectangular frame around legend key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOxuW.png)

The problem is that it is unclear that "Snow/ice" in the legend refers to a category because the key colour is invisible on a white background. For this reason, "Snow/ice" looks like a legend title rather than a legend key. I am aware that I can change the legend background with `tm_layout(legend.bg.color = "gray")`, but I prefer to keep the background white. Instead I would like to draw a thin black rectangular frame around each
legend key. Here is this idea implemented with ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_stars(aes(x, y, fill = cover_simplified), data = land_copy) +
  scale_fill_discrete(type = c("white", "lightblue", "brown")) +
  coord_sf() +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = "black"))
```

[map produced with ggplot2 with rectangular frame around each legend key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQbXj.png)

I would prefer to work with tmap instead of ggplot2 because the actual map I want to produce is more complex than the example above, so tmap is a better tool for my task. I am posting this question because I cannot find a function argument for `tm_layout()` that seems relevant for my problem. A Google search has not led me to useful information either.

Is there a way to produce the equivalent of ggplot2's `theme(legend.key = element_rect(color = "black")` with tmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an option for doing this directly in `tmap`. However, a `tmap` is drawn with grid graphics, so it is possible to capture the legend, change it, and draw it back. If you add the following lines after your code:

```r
g <- grid::grid.grab()
leg <- grid::getGrob(g, "legend")
leg$children[[2]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$gp$col <- "black"
leg$children[[2]]$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$gp$lwd <- 1
grid::seekViewport("outside_legend")
grid::grid.draw(leg)
```

You get:

[image]

If you want to save this as a pdf, you can't use `tmap_save`, since this is no longer a `tmap` object. Instead, get the plot looking as you would like, then do:

```r
g <- grid::grid.grab()

pdf("my_pdf.pdf")
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(g)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggested solution looks perfect in RStudio's default "Plots" tab. What do I need to do to save the amended plot as a PDF with `tmap_save()`? I have tried adding `tmap_save(filename = "test.pdf")` at the very end. The code runs without any errors, warnings or messages. However, test.pdf does not include the rectangular frames.

Comment: Thank you. Placing your PDF-related lines of code at the very end indeed generates the desired PDF. The first of these lines, `g <- grid::grid.grab()`, produces the warning: "In grabDL(warn, wrap, wrap.grobs, ...): viewport overwritten (grab MAY not be faithful)". I turned off the warning by passing the argument `warn = 1`. Still, I am wondering whether there is a better way that does not trigger the warning in the first place. Unfortunately, I am currently unfamiliar with grid, so I cannot tell what is causing the warning.

Comment: @MichaelGastner you can change that line to `suppressWarnings(g <- grid::grid.grab())` . The warning is expected, because you are drawing a "new" object onto the existing plot window.

Comment: OK, thanks. The problem that caused me to post this question was still a little bit more complicated. I had two legends, and I needed the rectangular frames only for the second legend. The solution in my special case was to replace `leg$children[[2]]$children[[2]]` by `leg$children[[2]]$children[[4]]`. I leave this comment here just in case anybody else runs into a similar problem.